# How do I sum the odd indexed numbers in a text file using python

Tags: python, text-files, python-3.7

I have a text file that reads: 1,2,3,4,5. 
I want to write a code that will add only the odd indexed number in the text file.

The code I have added all the numbers in the text file.

```
odd_indexed = 0
openthefile = open('GOT_ratings.txt', "r")

for line in openthefile:
    for num in line.split(','):
        odd_indexed = odd_indexed + float(num.strip())

print("The sum of your numbers is %.1f" %(odd_indexed))
```

I want it to add 1+3+5 = 9

Comment: This seems to loop over multiple lines. Do you want to add the odd-indexed numbers on each line, or the odd-indexed numbers as if all the lines were one big list? (i.e. what should happen with `1,2,3` [new line] `4,5,6`?)

Comment: Numbers at odd indexes would be `2` and `4`

Comment: yeah, if I'm counting from zero

Comment: @Lilian Indexes in Python start from zero. So I guess you want even indexes right?

Comment: What I want the code to do is pretty simple... I want it to add the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th, 11th,..., nth number on the text file.

Comment: Yeah, it is even indexes if I'm counting from zero. That's what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick (edit to `==1` if you want results for index starting from 1):

```
for i,num in enumerate(line.split(',')):
    if (i%2==0):
        odd_indexed+=float(num)
```

`enumerate` gives the index as well as the value itself, and you can check which one is odd (or even, in the case of your described desired output).

Comment: I'm happy to hear it helped :) . FYI dcg's suggestion below with the list comprehension is probably faster, in case it matters to you.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna sum up even indexes of every line you could do something like:

```
for line in openthefile:
    odd_indexed += sum([int(x) for i, x in enumerate(line.split(',')) if i%2==0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
odd_indexed = 0
i=0
openthefile = open('GOT_ratings.txt', "r")

for line in openthefile:
    for num in line.split(','):
        if i%2!= True:
          odd_indexed = odd_indexed + float(num.strip())
          i+=1
        else:
          odd_indexed = odd_indexed 
          i+=1


print("The sum of your numbers is %.1f" %(odd_indexed))
```

Answer (score 2):

One line solution with numpy's genfromtxt. No need to do loops.

For even indices:

```
import numpy as np
ans=sum(np.genfromtxt('GOT_ratings.txt',delimiter=',')[::2])
```

For odd indices:

```
import numpy as np
ans=sum(np.genfromtxt('GOT_ratings.txt',delimiter=',')[1::2])
```

Information about genfromtxt can be found here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: I mostly use numpy while working on Anaconda/Jupyter notebook. I'm still yet to pip load numpy on my python. Thanks very much for the reference and answer, I appreciate.

Comment: @Lilian yes using numpy i think will be way faster especially for numeric calculation.

Answer (score 1):

the key point is use `enumerate`, you can deal with index by that. but 1, 3, 5's indexes is 0, 2, 4, which is even, not odd. Here is sample code:

```
odd_indexed = 0
line = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
for i, num in enumerate(line.split(',')):
    # for beginner
    if i % 2 == 1:
        odd_indexed = odd_indexed + float(num.strip())

    # more concise way
    # odd_indexed += float(num.strip()) if i % 2 else 0

print("The odd sum of your numbers is %.1f" % (odd_indexed))
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )